# PHP/HTML - Read table row where radio button is active after form submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a webpage where a table lists a bunch of meals for a whole month. I want to be able to use a **radio button** at the **beginning of each row** ( 1 row - one day ) to select which meal will be the next one.
The reasoning behind this is that I have another webpage which will display "next meal : XXX" where XXX is read from the database ( something like "where nextmeal=1" ).
So basically what I want is that when **I activate one of my radio buttons** the meal in this line should get a nextmeal=1 in the database entry. 
**Database table** has the following **columns = date,meat,veggie,nextmeal**
I tried some suggestions on how to send active radio button values to the server but I wasn't able to paste the correct date to the server to do the correct query.

Source code for the table webpage :

```
<?php
require_once 'db_config.inc.php';
require_once 'functionsgerichte.php';
$db = new mysqli($db_server,$db_user,$db_password,$db_database);
if(!empty($_GET['monat'])) {$monat = $_GET['monat'];} //define default_month
else $monat = 14;
if(!empty($_GET['jahr'])) {$activ_year = $_GET['jahr'];} //define  default_year
else $activ_year = 2010;
?>
<html>
<style>
#gerichtetext {
width: 100%;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0px;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
color:black;
border: none;
outline:none;
}
input[type=radio] {
width: 100%;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0px;
height: 50%;

}

</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="../includes/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body bgcolor = '#e3e3e3'>

<form action style='float:left'>
<select name='monat' size='1'>

<?php 
        $monate = array("","Januar","Februar","M&auml;rz","April","Mai","Juni","Juli","August","September","Oktober","November","Dezember");  //
        for($i=1; $i<=12;$i++)
        {
            if($monat== 14) echo "<option value=".$i.">". $monate[$i] ."";
            else if($i == $_GET['monat']) echo "<option selected='selected' value=".$i.">". $monate[$i] ."";
            else echo "<option value=".$i.">". $monate[$i] ."";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        $jahrabfrage="SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(timestamp) as jahre FROM essenslog ORDER BY year(timestamp)";
        $jab = mysqli_query($db,$jahrabfrage);
        echo "<select name='jahr' size='1'>";
        while($year = mysqli_fetch_object($jab))
        {
            if($year->jahre == $_GET["jahr"]) echo "<option value='$activ_year' selected='selected'> $year->jahre</option>"; 
            else echo "<option value='$year->jahre'>$year->jahre</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='send'>

</form>

<?php

$month=$_GET['monat'];  $year = $_GET['jahr']; // Variablen übergeben 

$unixtime = "$year-$month-21 12:00:00";         //21. Tag des Monats des Jahres

$unixmonat = date("t", strtotime($unixtime));   //Ermittlung der Anzahl der Tage des Monats des Jahres

$Tage = Array_Fill(1, $unixmonat,42);           //Auffüllen eines Arrays (von 1-Anzahl der Tage eines Monats)

//Ermittlung der Anzahl der DB-Einträge

$groesse = count($alle);

$tmp = array_keys($Tage);

$LetzterTag = end($tmp)+1;

$temptimer = 0;

$AlleTage = array();

for($i=0; $i<$LetzterTag;$i++) //Erstellung von je einem Object je Tag

{ 
$ActiveDay[$i] = new NeuerTag;      
array_push($AlleTage,$ActiveDay[$i]);

}       

$i = 0; //initialisieren des Tagecounters

?>

<form action='gericht2db.php' id='MyForm' method='get' >

<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $month; ?>' name='monat'/>

<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $year; ?>' name='jahr'/>

<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $LetzterTag; ?>' name='letztertag'/>

<input type='hidden' value='' name='radio_row'/>

<input style='float:right' onclick='check()' id='submit-button' type='submit' value='SPEICHERN'/>

<table border ='1' width ='100%' height ='100%' style='clear:both'><tr bgcolor='#666666' style='color:white'><td width='5%'>NächstesEssen</td><td width='10%'>Wochentag</td><td width='10%'>Datum</td><td width='35%'>Fleisch</td><td width='35%'>Vegetarisch</td></tr>
<?php
for($i=1; $i<$LetzterTag;$i++)
{
    $time = "$year-$month-$i";
    if(date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Saturday" ||date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Sunday" || in_array(strtotime($time), $Freietage)) $ActiveDay[$i]->Feiertag = true;
    if($ActiveDay[$i]->Begin == 0)
    {
        $color = "#969696";
        if(date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Saturday" ||date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Sunday" || in_array(strtotime($time), $Freietage))
        {
            $color = "#86191a";
            $fontcolor = "#a1a1a1";
        }
        else
        {
            $color = "#969696";
            $fontcolor = "black";
        }           
        echo "<tr bgcolor='$color' style='color:$fontcolor'>";  
        echo "<td >";
        if(date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Saturday" ||date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Sunday" || in_array(strtotime($time), $Freietage))
        {
            echo "</td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<input type='radio' id='radio_".$i."' name='radio' value='radio_".$i."' />";
            echo "</td>";
        }           
        echo "<td>".date('l',strtotime($time))."</td>";
        echo "<td>".date("d", strtotime($time)).".".date("m", strtotime($time)).".".date("Y", strtotime($time))."</td>";
        $fleisch=fleisch(date("Y", strtotime($time))."-".date("m", strtotime($time))."-".date("d", strtotime($time)));
        $veggie=veggie(date("Y", strtotime($time))."-".date("m", strtotime($time))."-".date("d", strtotime($time)));
        $temp="fleisch_".$i ;
        echo "<td >";
        if(date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Saturday" ||date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Sunday" || in_array(strtotime($time), $Freietage))
        {
            echo "</td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<input type='text' id='gerichtetext' name='".$temp."' value='".$fleisch."'/></td>";
            echo "</td>";
        }
        $temp="veggie_".$i ;
        echo "<td>";
        if(date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Saturday" ||date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Sunday" || in_array(strtotime($time), $Freietage))
        {
            echo "</td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<input type='text' id='gerichtetext' name='".$temp."' value='".$veggie."'/></td>";
            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "&nbsp</td>";


}

?>


</tr>
</table>

</form>

<script>

$('tbody').on('change', ':radio', function()

{
var line = $('input[name=radio]:checked').val();
// alert(line);

});

</script>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">


$.ajax({

 url: 'gericht2db.php',

type: 'POST',

data: 'radio_row=blablubeldiblub' ,

success: function(data) {
//Optional callback function on success

 }

});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

And the code for the form click :

```
require_once 'db_config.inc.php';
require_once 'functionsgerichte.php';
$connection = mysql_connect($db_server,$db_user,$db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_database,$connection);
$LetzterTag = $_REQUEST['letztertag'];
$AlleTage = array();
$year= $_REQUEST['jahr'];
$month= $_REQUEST['monat'];
for($i=0; $i<$LetzterTag;$i++) { 
    //Erstellung von je einem Object je Tag
    $ActiveDay[$i] = new NeuerTag;      
    array_push($AlleTage,$ActiveDay[$i]);
}       
$i = 0 ;
for($i=1; $i<$LetzterTag;$i++) {
    $time = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$i;
    if(date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Saturday" ||date('l',strtotime($time)) == "Sunday" || in_array(strtotime($time), $Freietage)) 
        $ActiveDay[$i]->Feiertag = true;

    if($ActiveDay[$i]->Begin == 0) {    
        $naechstesessen= $_REQUEST['naechstesessen'];
        $fleischrequest='fleisch_'.$i ;
        $fleisch= $_REQUEST[$fleischrequest];
        $veggierequest='veggie_'.$i ;
        $veggie= $_REQUEST[$veggierequest];
        $connection=mysql_connect('oris', 'root', 'orhro');
        mysql_select_db('anwesenheit',$connection);

        if ($naechstesessen== "radio_1") {
            $sql = "update gericht set naechstesessen='1'";         
            try {
                $query = mysql_query($sql);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }   
            $sql = "update gericht set naechstesessen='1' where Datum='".$time."'";
            try {
                $query = mysql_query($sql);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }               
        }
        $sql = "DELETE from gericht where Datum='".$time."'";
        try {
            $query = mysql_query($sql);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO gericht (Datum,Fleisch,Vegetarisch) VALUES ('".$time."','".$fleisch."','".$veggie."')";
        try {
            $query = mysql_query($sql);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
Header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
```

EDIT: I also want to keep the previously clicked radio button to remain active after I clicked on my form, added form to source code.

Comment: Would not it be simpler to store the dates for the meals?

Comment: You just need an array to store selected mean on submit

Comment: Sure, but im still struggling to find the correct line for the date i want to store. I added a bit to make my question more specific

Comment: @Shadow How would you store the meals? I would still need a way so somehow select the next meal and keep it selected on page reload until I choose another meal on another day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created HTML as per your UI.

And perform operation like once user can select any radio button and click on SAVE button radio button value stored in database.

On page page load previous selection will be there.

I have capture video for the same, Please see it once and let me know if you have any concerns for the same..

URL : http://screencast.com/t/ebTv28LHT4
**PHP**

```
<?php
$db_server = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_database = "team44";

$db = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_database);

  $suc="";
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $naechstesessen = $_POST['naechstesessen'];
    $jahrabfrage = "INSERT INTO post VALUES (NULL,'" . $naechstesessen . "','details')";
    $jab = mysqli_query($db, $jahrabfrage);

    if($jab){
        $suc= "Data Inserted";
    }
}
?>
```

HTML**strong text**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width:100%;
            }
            table  th {
                background: rgb(102, 102, 102) none repeat scroll 0 0;
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            }
            table  td {
                background: #969696;
                color: #000;
            }
            table, td, th {
                border: 2px solid #878787;
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 11px;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
            }
            td:first-child input {
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                text-align: center;
            }
            td:first-child,
            td:nth-child(2) {
                width: 10%;
            }
            .speichern {
                float: right;
            }
            div.table-responsive {
                overflow-x: auto;
            }
            .bg-red td{background:#86191A;color:#969696;}
            @media(max-width:767px){table{width:1000px;}}
            .month,.year,.send,.speichern{ font-size: 10px;
                                           font-weight: bold;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <select class="month">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <select class="year">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
        <form method="POST">

            <input type="submit" class="send" value="send" name="send" />
            <input type="submit" class="speichern" value="save" name="save" />
            <div class="table-responsive">

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>NachstesEssen</th>
                        <th>Wochentag</th>
                        <th>Datum</th>
                        <th>Fleisch</th>
                        <th>Vegetarisch</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $select = "select naechstesessen from post order by id DESC LIMIT 1";
                    $result = mysqli_query($db, $select);
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen"  value="1.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '1.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?>></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen"  value="2.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '2.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?>></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="3.11.2016"> <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '3.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="4.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '4.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?>></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bg-red">
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="5.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '5.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?>></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bg-red">
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="6.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '6.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?>></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="7.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '7.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?>></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="8.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '8.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?>></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="9.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '9.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="10.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '10.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="12.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '12.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bg-red">
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="13.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '13.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bg-red">
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="14.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '14.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="15.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '15.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="16.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '16.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="17.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '17.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="18.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '18.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bg-red">
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="19.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '19.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bg-red">
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="20.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '20.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="21.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '21.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?> ></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="naechstesessen" value="22.11.2016" <?php
                            if ($row['naechstesessen'] == '22.11.2016') {
                                echo "checked";
                            }
                            ?>></td>
                        <td>Peter</td>
                        <td>Griffin</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                <center><h1 style="color: green"><?php echo $suc; ?></h1></center>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the same

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will test it and let you know if it also worked for me asap!

Comment: Thank you again, that solved my issue, not sure if it was the div that you used or the POST method but im glad that it works now, tagged your answer as the solution, THANKS!

Comment: @Flayckz,Anytime :-) , It will be grate if you give Up-vote for the same

Comment: I would do, but im not yet at 15 reputation, sorry

Comment: @Flayckz Oh its okay , Thnak you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer...

Chaneg the radio type name as radio[]

Example `"<input type='radio' id='radio_".$i."' name='radio[]' value='radio_".$i."' />;`

Stored radio value in "radio[]"

On submit busson clcik get the array like

```
$data = $_POST['radio'];
Print_r($data);
```

I hope it's helpful to you..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132375/discussion-on-answer-by-mr-hk-php-html-read-table-row-where-radio-button-is-a).